# How to loop through JSON object values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I have a JSON Object and I want to loop through the values:

```
$json = '{"1":a,"2":b,"3":c,"4":d,"5":e}';
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
for($i=0; $i<count($obj['a']); $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

I want the `$i` to display the `abcde` that are the values in the object.

Comment: `print_r($obj)`

Comment: `$i<count($obj['a'])` should be `$i<count($obj)`. You want to count the total elements in the array, not the elements in the first value, which is 0 in this case. Alternatively `foreach` is more readable.

Comment: line 4 is thus: for($i=0; $i<count($obj); $i++) {

Comment: Your json is invalid. All alpha-characters need to be in quotes. `{"1": "a", ... etc}`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try using.

```
$json = '{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c","4":"d","5":"e"}';
 $obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach($obj as $key => $value) 
{
echo 'Your key is: '.$key.' and the value of the key is:'.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The shortest way to iterate it and this way you don't care about index is to use `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($obj as $value) {
 echo $value;
}
```

For example you don't have a index 0 in your `$obj`. From what I see it starts from 1. This way it's working with any index (not just numeric)

Comment: How is this different from the answer above which should also work with any $key

Comment: @Pancho It tells the reader that you don't need the key in a `foreach` loop and it also works without.

Comment: @Lampe2020 I understand that these answers came out at exactly the same time which is I suppose why it happened and that this one was actually first. However should timing not have been the case I stand by my comment that only one of these answers was needed - the other could just have added a comment to the first.

Comment: @Pancho Probably, yes. You've got that point.